# Dart catching _CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)

Tags: exception, dart-null-safety

In null-safety dart is there a way to try..catch specifically _CastError (Null check operator used on a null value) type of errors?
I need to avoid_catches_without_on_clauses (catching everything).

Let's not get into discussions on checking for null beforehand instead of catching and all the dangers of using it.

Answer (score 1):

`_CastError` is subtype of `TypeError`, so you should be able to:

```
on TypeError catch (e){
          // handle exception
        }
```